# Very slow IE9 performance with a capable computer

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I just built a new computer with a Core i7-3770 chip, 32 GB of RAM, a 240 GB SSD boot drive and an Asus GT640 video card. IE9 is very slow and crashes often.

Everything I read seems to point to the video drivers and IE9 compatibility as the source of the issues.

I have updated the drivers and told IE9 to use software rendering instead of hardware rendering.

What else could be the issue?

Comment: You do know that software rendering will be much slower than hardware rendering, right? Any suggestion to use that probably is to get around potential crashes due to the video card.

Comment: Is IE9 the only program with issues?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a virus. Do you have antivirus installed? either way run a virus scan right away.

I would also recommend downloading [combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) (preferably from another computer) and running that to check for viruses and other nasty items.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried both the default 32-bit pinned IE, and the 64-bit IE that can be found in the Start Menu? The latter's the one I use now when I have need for IE, instead of the former. If you already haven't done so, try re-enabling hardware rendering and test the 64-bit version.

FWIW, I tried both versions (fully patched with latest updates) for some time on multiple PCs (with integrated/external graphics), and even though they are nowhere *near* as capable as yours, I had absolutely no problems surfing the web with IE9 (combined with EasyList TPLs of course, never leave home without them!)